# Different package names to be added in desired capabilities in appium

Tags: java, android, appium, desiredcapabilities

We have an android app which is composed of two different apps. 
Launcher activity is present in 1 project which has a package name

```
in.foo.android.main.MainActivity
```

while app package which is shown in uiautomator view is something like

```
com.abc.android.debug
```

in desired capabilites I am setting following :

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE ,"com.abc.android.debug");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,"in.foo.android.main.MainActivity");
```

So getting below error

`com.abc.android.debug/in.foo.android.main.MainActivity` is not a launchable activity

Here appium is adding package name by default before the main activity.

can someone provide some help here.

Comment: As i understand you are using wrong APP_ACTIVITY, you can check it again

Comment: @AlImran :  When running this command from terminal app is getting launched :  adb shell am start -n com.abc.android.debug/in.foo.android.main.MainActivity. But with Appium it gives the error

Comment: Do you have any splash screen of this application ?

Comment: if you have the splash screen, then you can use the splash activity as 'appActivity'

Comment: Example: 
`com.abc.android.debug.in.foo.android.main.SplshScreen`

Answer (score 0):

**First**

1. Go to CMD as admin type *adb devices*
2. Make sure that your device already opened the apps that you want
3. go to cmd and type *adb shell dumpsys window | find "mCurrentFocus"*

[this the exp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ADsL.png)

Thats command will showing the current activity

**Second**

1. Install the APK Info from playstore (idk if you try on the appstore)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wt.apkinfo&hl=in&gl=US

2. Open the APK Info
3. Search your apps s name and click it
4. You will see this screen
   [appdetail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNiKw.png)
5. Scroll down and check the activities
   [activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNOmt.png)
6. You will see all of the activity on the apps
   [existingactivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5zuL.png)